# exception for callable in phpstan

Tags: php, callback, static-analysis, phpstan, checked-exceptions

how can I describe the exceptions thrown from callable in phpDoc?
For example I have:

```
/**
 * @param callable(int): bool
 */
function (callable $foo, int $number): ?bool
{
    try {
        return $foo($number);
    } catch (InvalidNumberException) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And I want something like this:

```
/**
 * @param callable(int): bool throws InvalidNumberException
 */
function (callable $foo, int $number): ?bool
{
    try {
        return $foo($number);
    } catch (InvalidNumberException) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct place to document the callable. You might [declare an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649197/how-can-i-use-phpdoc-to-type-hint-the-parameters-of-a-callable) that the callable needs to adhere to, and then document that.

Comment: To document exceptions for a callable in PHPDoc, you can't specify the exception in the @param line for the callable. Instead, you should describe the potential exception in the general description of the function or the parameter.

Comment: I'm trying to limit the signature of callbacks. I need phpstan to show an error when I try to pass functions without the exception specified in the signature.